# Underscore notation in play framework

Tags: playframework, naming-conventions

What exactly is the difference between `${post.title}` and `${_post.title}`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In what context? I think what you are probably confused about is the custom template tags. When using template tags, parameters that are passed into the tag have their names prepended with an underscore.

So

```
#{hello name:'Bob' /}
```

Would have its value accessible from within the tag as `${_name}`, so you would do something like

```
Hello ${_name} !
```

You can see more of this at the Play documentation for custom tags - http://www.playframework.org/documentation/1.2.4/templates#tags.